# How do I disable activity notifications in byobu with the screen backend?

Tags: gnu-screen, byobu

In a recent ubuntu update, my byobu screens started highlighting the window names when there's been activity. This is annoying me, I'd rather just have active/inactive displayed (as it did before the update). How can I disable it? I've found instructions for how with tmux, but I'm using the screen backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this to your `~/.byobu/.screenrc`:

```
monitor off    
defmonitor off
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*